# BreezeJS - server validation changed in version 1.4.4

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I've updated breezejs from version 1.4.1 to 1.4.4. For server-side validation, I was handling the AfterSaveEntitiesDelegate on the ContextProvider and throwing EntityErrorsException().

In the release notes I read:

> The Breeze WebApi response to any SaveChanges operation that has
>   validation errors now returns a 403 status code, instead of a 200.
>   This has no effect on any Breeze code but will be noticeable to anyone
>   watching Breeze's network traffic.

However, the new 403 error does not have any details about the validation error or any inner exceptions that would indicate it is a validation error. Instead the error is: "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details." There is no "Response" property. Also, now my client-side code no longer "understands" this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this exception is not intended to be caught and wrapped into an HttpResponseMessage. My code for the BreezeController SaveChanges() api was:

```
try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _commDataService.SaveChanges(pSaveData, shouldValidate));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
```

This was returning the right exception but with the wrong status code (500 instead of 403 as expected by updated breezejs client code.

I added a new catch to pass along the breeze-constructed response message:

```
            catch (System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException responseException)
        {
            //todo: logger call.
            return responseException.Response;
        }
```